# TypeError in AlbumPhotosController#create no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am creating the app of gallery that stores the photos as well as albums in it. I took help from the following site: [Multiple image upload with carrierwave](http://bobintornado.github.io/rails/2015/12/29/Multiple-Images-Uploading-With-CarrierWave-and-PostgreSQL-Array.html)

But I am facing the error of

> TypeError in AlbumPhotosController#create no implicit conversion of nil into String

This is my code for controller:

```
def create
@album_photo = AlbumPhoto.new(album_photo_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @album_photo.save
    format.html { redirect_to @album_photo, notice: 'Album photo was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @album_photo }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @album_photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def album_photo_params
  params.require(:album_photo).permit(:album_id,{albumphotos: []})
end
```

This is my Model:

```
#AlbumPhoto Model
class AlbumPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  mount_uploader :albumphotos, AlbumphotoUploader
end

#Album Model
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_many :album_photos
end
```

This is my view:

```
 <%= form_for(@album_photo) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.file_field :albumphotos, multiple: true %>
    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo, mount_uploader should be mount_uploaders (from the [tutorial sample code](https://github.com/bobintornado/sample-gallery-app-with-carrierwave/blob/master/app/models/gallery.rb))

Comment: I tried this also. It gives me the following error: 
    undefined method `mount_uploaders' for #<Class:0x007ff372b24158>     Did you mean? mount_uploader